# How to animate UITextField.text when becomesActive and resigns?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How is that the both `text` & `placeHolder` properties are animated when the textfield becomes `FirstResponder` is apps like Safari for example (please take a look at the link for further reference)? I have read thru the documentation both Apple's and some online search but no luck with this, can anyone here shed some light on the subject? Thanks

See attached: http://tinypic.com/r/2nsuwqb/8

Comment: For the app like Safari its a UISearchBar not a UITextField. You will get the same animation in your app if you use a UISearchBar..

Comment: Wow thanks @Ty_ I just read over the docs for UISearchBar I had no idea it even existed!